# Send SonarQube link in mail from Jenkins

Tags: java, email, templates, jenkins, sonarqube

I am using Jenkins for Orchestrate a build of a Java Project. I am scanning this project source with SonarQube Scanner in pre-build phase. I need to send a mail for both pass and fail case to a list of Recipient.

Client want this SonarQube result link in the mail.  I manage to configure Jenkins to shoot the mail but I cant find any document which specify how to add SonarQube result.

Jenkins do print the link in logs.
I am using `Jenkins 2.25`, `SonarQube 5.6.4` and mail plugin `Email Extension Plugin 2.58`.

Please help.

Comment: Title says SonarQube link and Description says SonarQube result. Which one you are looking?

Comment: Link to sonarqube result

Answer (score 2):

You can use `BUILD_LOG_REGEX` token to extract required information from the log. The syntax is as follows:

```
${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex, linesBefore, linesAfter, maxMatches, showTruncatedLines, substText}
```

Exemplary email notification content with a Sonar result URL (in a case of successful scan):

```
SonarQube result URL: ${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex=".*ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse (.*)", showTruncatedLines=false, substText="$1"}
```